# Alert user with UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, sdk, uialertview

Just need your thought on a problem and how to approach it.
I have an app that normally doesn't ask to connect to the web (unless user desires to send an email from within the app). 
I d like to inform the user every now and then BUT not all the time with lets say i.e. news and daily tips etc at start up. 
How would you approach this? 
Would I just pop a uialertview at startup? And how do I prevent it from poping up all the time and only pop up whenever I have something new to say?

I'm a bit lost here, and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some realtime scenario? How will you know that now you need to show pop up ?

Comment: When you have something new to say, you can use the alert view. I dont think there is any better way.

Comment: Save a date on NSUserDefault when you want the first UIAlert to appear. Once that gets triggered, reset the date to the current value + your desired time lapse and pop the UIAlert again. You can check for the values in your App Delegate didEnterForeground method.

Answer (score 1):

rising a notification which declares the time as approached to display an alert view is a good idea as stated by jignesh.
add a notification to the method or scenario which states the situation to display an alert and when the situation occurs just display a alertView.

hope it helps u

TNQ

Comment: I really wouldn't like to use dates as I don't have specific dates or fixed date intervals. I would rather have the alert view to check every time the web and if there is anything there to be displayed ok and if not just won't show up. If that makes any sense...

Comment: my intention is also the same.i think using a BOOL variable u can determine whether a update is found.as soon as a update is found make the BOOL yes and write a condition to raise when BOOL is YES.and after a alert is raised make the BOOL as NO.but there should be a method or class which searches the web frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement push notification to alert the user about new things come from server....

Comment: yeah, sorry, getting to the comment. A push notification is a bad idea. why? Because you don't want news and tips from your app to be pushed at any time. He wants them to "pop up" on start up of his app, if there's something new to say.

Comment: Push notification is probably a better idea in the long run as the UIAlert messages would have to be "hard coded" into the app whereas with push you can send whatever you want, whenever you want. [edit] to say they don't REALLY have to be hard coded but push notifications is definitely more practical.

Comment: let say for example, there is new tips added on server side, and application is closed, don't you think, that it is the best way to inform user by providing push notification to user about daily news and daily tips coming, and the logic is on server side, how we want user to notify and how many times user needs notification per day, that can be implemented on server side.

Comment: I would not keep an app on my phone that Push alerted me every time the developer wanted to send me a tip or some news. I'd remove it. Its a terrible idea. But ON STARTING the app, if, occasionally, it said "Hi there, you know blah blah blah" then that wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: This exactly what I want to do Thomas and I agree with you. How would you approach this? Would it be a good idea to check on start up for a specific say "string" on a server and then if it exits push it to the user if not just don't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's my idea.

You need a feed on your server. This you can send a time to. The time you send will be the last time you checked for new messages. The script on the server needs to return all messages AFTER the time you send.

On the app you will get the response (probably best in plist or xml format) which will contain all new messages you want to send (after the time you sent). At this point you now want to log the current time. You should use an NSUserDefault for this (so you can get all NEW messages from the server next time). You also want to put the new messages into an NSUserDefault (use a mutable array of strings).

On starting the app you want to check your NSUserDefaults to see if there are any messages (`if([[defaults messagesArray] count] > 0)`). If there are then UIAlertView them (one at a time). And after you do `[alert show]` you want to remove them from the array.

Just thinking off the top of my head, let me know if none of that makes sense! :p